# Unable to check and uncheck the dynamically rendered checkboxes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am iterating over the permissions and make checkbox checked if permission included in a predefined values(i.e val) and make checkbox unchecked otherwise, which it did well, but when I click the rendered checkboxes to check or to uncheck it do nothing.

I can't check or uncheck after I rendered my checkboxes. I need your help , thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `role.permissions` is never getting updated, so the checkbox `checked` attribute stays as its initial value. Are you using [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)? If so, you can add an `onChange` event handler to your `input` to update your `role.permissions`.

Comment: Oh I never had the idea of updating roles.permissions, thanks for the idea . I will give you a feedback on that

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the ternary operation in `checked={role?.permissions?.includes(val[i]) ? true : false}` is redundant and can be simplified to just `checked={role?.permissions?.includes(val[i])}`, since the value of that property will be either true or false anyway.

Secondly, by setting `value=` to true or false, you are freezing the checkbox to that value. You can omit that setting, as the value attribute will be submitted according to the checked or unchecked value. Also, typically you assign `value=checked` or `value=unchecked`, not true and false.

Answer (score 0):

use map function and useState to control your checkbox values.